# Date to XMLGregorianCalendar with specific format

Tags: java, xml, date, calendar

I am getting a Date object, which i need to convert to XMLGregorian Calendar specific format

I tried below ways

```
String formattedDate = sdf.format(categoryData.getBulkCollectionTime()); //yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(formattedDate);
dataListType.setTimestamp(xmlCal);
```

I am getting an exception, for sure I am doing wrong here. But I want to format the Date object into specified format, which is done by sdf.format perfectly.

But how do I create the XMLGregorianCalendar object for the same (from formattedDate)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by the date object itself:

```
String formattedDate = sdf.format(categoryData.getBulkCollectionTime()); //yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
convertStringToXmlGregorian(formattedDate);


public XMLGregorianCalendar convertStringToXmlGregorian(String dateString)
{
      try {
            Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
            GregorianCalendar gc = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
            gc.setTime(date);
            return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // Optimize exception handling
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } 

}
```

Comment: I tried with your example, But in the output value I am getting "2013-01-18T07:46:00.000" as output. I don't want "T"

Answer (score 6):

You should fixed your date format:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String date = sdf.format(new Date());
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(date);
```

Comment: in Output I am getting "2013-01-18T07:46:00.000" I don't want T

Comment: you can use any format for output, but newXMLGregorianCalendar(dateTime) accepts only dates in XSD dateTime format, see API