# XMLGregorianCalendar not displayed in the right format when marshalled

Tags: java, xml, date, jaxb, marshalling

I'm getting some dates from the database, putting them into objects of classes derived from an XSD schema using JAXB and then marshalling the objects to an XML file.

One of the derived classes has an XMLGregorianCalendar field, and I want the date that I put there to be written into the XML file in the "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" format.

Following the instructions from the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392811/date-to-xmlgregoriancalendar-with-specific-format) question does not solve my problem. This is what I'm doing:

```
String formattedDate = sdf.format(dateFromTheDatabase);
        gc1 = convertStringToXmlGregorian(formattedDate);
        gc1.setTimezone(60);
components.setDate(gc1);
```

The function that I'm using (more or less copied from an answer to the above linked question):

```
public XMLGregorianCalendar convertStringToXmlGregorian(String dateString)     throws DatatypeConfigurationException
{
    try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");    
            java.util.Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
            GregorianCalendar gc = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
            gc.setTime(date);
            return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } 
}
```

The date that I get in my XML when I marshal the objects I filled:

2015-06-03+01:00

...whereas I want my date to be in this format:

2015-06-03T00:00:00

**Things I also tried:**

- replacing
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
  with
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
- replacing

  ```
      DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
  ```

  with

  ```
      DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(
      gc.get(Calendar.YEAR), gc.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, gc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
      gc.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 0,0,0,60);
  ```

Comment: Somewhere in JAXB you need to set the right data type using the annotation `@XmlSchemaType(name="dateTime")`. Probably you only have set "date" instead of "dateTime".

Comment: Your components.date property should have a type of [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) or [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).  The JAXB specification states that those types are automatically mapped to the schema dateTime type, whose [lexical format](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dateTime-lexical-mapping) already matches what you want.  No need to use DateFormats at all.

Comment: @Meno Hochschild: You're right. Please write that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Okay, now my comment as answer:**

Somewhere in JAXB (you have not yet shown your relevant Java file) you need to set the right data type using the annotation @XmlSchemaType(name="dateTime"). Probably you only have set "date" instead of "dateTime" so the time part of your `XMLGregorianCalendar`-object has been suppressed by JAXB-layer.

**Another advise:**

What you have presented so far seems in part to be double work - with regards to the usage of `SimpleDateFormat`. If your input is already an object of type `java.util.Date` then you don't need to format and parse it again. Just pass it as argument to a `GregorianCalendar.setTime()`-method.